# Configuring evolutions script for different environment

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

These are my configuration files for both development and testing environments. I'm displaying only the db configuration section.

**dev.conf**

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb"
db.default.user=admin
db.default.password=admin
applyEvolutions.default=true
evolutionplugin=disabled
```

**test.conf**

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mytestdb"
db.default.user=admin
db.default.password=admin
applyEvolutions.default=true
evolutionplugin=enabled
```

Basically I'm planning to execute the evolutions db script *only* to the testing database. So I will clean up the records before triggering the test-script.

Based on [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Evolutions) the evolution scripts has to be put in folder with the same name as the datasource, which is `default` in this case:

> ~/conf/evolutions/default/

**My question:**

Is there a way for me to put the scripts in different location and set the configuration file to refer to that one instead? I'd love to put the test scripts in this path:

> ~/conf/evolutions/test/

It'll be troublesome for me if in one way or another someone accidentally enable the evolutions in the `dev.conf` file and since both configuration files share the same datasource name(`default`) then all the clean-up queries in the `default` folder are executed.

Another workaround that I can think of right now is by using different datasource name for different environments but this will imply code change because then the application doesn't use the `default` datasource anymore. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: any luck with this? I am stuck with the same issue and don't seem to find much help :(

Comment: No, I didn't :( I haven't tried again since then. Not sure if they've done something about it. you have found the answer you can put the answer here and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the evolutions logic directly from a text fixture of some kind?
`play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions.applyFor(dbName, path)` seems like it might do the trick.

Comment: This way I'll have to clean up the database for every test file. If possible I'd rather clean up the database only once right before the test starts.